# Is there a way to add more options to already existing ones in System Settings on MacOS?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, settings, default

I'm looking into developing an app that would extend *System Settings* is some way, that is, I would like to add one more option to already existing options.

For example, on **Appearance** menu, there is an option called "*Sidebar Icon Size*" that has these 3 options (*Small*, *Medium*, *Large*):

[image: MacOS System Preferences]

Is there any way to extend any of these settings with more Options when my app is installed/running in background ? For example, I would like for this one to extend it with options `Extra Small` and `Extra Large`.

Comment: Nope.  Those preference panes are on a cryptographically sealed read-only system partition.

Comment: @red_menace Is there any way than to override those settings with my custom App settings when it's running ?

Comment: There is no guarantee that overriding the preference would provide the "Extra" you want - for example, if it is just a value for an internal enumeration, you may need to perform all the icon manipulations yourself.